# Check if record exists in ANY column

Tags: php, laravel, database

In my Laravel application, I need to check if any of my 20 columns in a table has a specific record. I've searched for this answer, but only found a way to check if it exists in a specific column, but i need to check in all columns, and i was wondering if there's a way to do that without a loop, something like:

```
DB::table('cart')->where($fileId->id)->exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$field->id` is the search term. You can try

```php
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('cart');

$query = DB::table('cart');

$firstColumn = array_shift($columns);
$query->where($firstColumn, $field->id);

foreach($columns as $column) {
    $query->orWhere($column, $field->id);
}

$result = $query->exists();
```

Comment: As i said in the question, i was wondering if there's a way to do that without any loops..

Comment: Without a loop you will have to write `->where('column_name', $searchTerm)` for each of the 20 columns i.e 20 times.  What is the problem with loop?

Comment: yes, i know, but i was wondering if there was a way. I don't want any loops because i already have 2 loops inside the function, and it will consume a lot of processing in this thing..

Comment: Let me remind that here the loop is just building up the query. IT is not making/performing query to the database in each loop iteration. So in that sense there's no performance pitfall to look out for.

Comment: hmmmmm i see.. that do changes things... Thank you for this explanation!!!